# skin issue telerik contols

Tags: asp.net, css, telerik, dotnetnuke, skin

I am having styling issues with some telerik controls on an asp.net 3.5 page in DNN. The controls skin correctly in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE (even v9).

This happens for 1 radGrid and 1 RadlistBox on the site but all other rad controls including other radgrids style correctly.

I've been comparing the html and computed styles using dev tools and it seems that in IE none/not all of the styles are coming through from WebResource.axd.

Screenshot comparisons below;

[![Chrome][1]][1]

[![IE][2]][2]

Been going round in circles with this. Let me know if more info/code needed. Thanks
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIoDA.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j29gL.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are hitting the CSS limit in IE? See http://blogs.telerik.com/blogs/posts/10-05-03/internet_explorer_css_limits.aspx for more details.

Comment: Thanks, added a RadStyleSheetManager to the page which fixed the issue.

Comment: I still have this error, and can't find a way to fix. Can you please explain the details of your 'RadStyleSheetManager' fix ?